# tasksel: apt-get failed (100) while installing Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: ubuntu, desktop

I am trying to install Ubuntu Desktop using tasksel in Ubuntu Server 18. It is working perfectly fine for all the other packages/softwares but showing tasksel: apt-get failed (100) while installing Desktop.

Please give me solution.

Comment: I just struck the same issue, but with Ubuntu server 20.04. it stops at file 973 of 978, so I guess tasksel are trying to connect to an faulty server..